# Why am I getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices and not the float value while finding Median of two sorted arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

I have two sorted arrays and I am trying to find median of two sorted arrays.**For example,if input is nums1 = [1,3], nums2 = [2] then the output will median=2.00000 and if the input is p = [1,2], t = [3,4] then the output will be median=2.50000** I have added both the arrays together and sorted them and later by using  their lengths I have tried to calculate the correct value. Below is my code

```
class Solution(object):
def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1, nums2):

    nums1.extend(nums2)
    nums1.sort()

    if len(nums1)%2 ==0:
        a = len(nums1)/2
        return float(nums1[a]+nums1[a-1])/float(2)
    else:
        a = len(nums1) / 2
        return float(nums1[a])

if __name__ == "__main__":
p = [1,3]
t = [2]
print(Solution().findMedianSortedArrays(p,t))
```

Below is the error in the logs.

```
 return float(nums1[a])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Because](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

> Division of integers yields a float

but you could trivially check this by printing out `a` just before using it as an index. And the error is extremely clear that `a` *is* a float at that point.

Either coerce it to int, as

```
nums1[int(a)]
```

or use floor division, with

```
a = len(nums1) // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In python a division always returns a float, you cannot use a float for indexing lists or other iterables, convert it to an int first.

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]

a[1/1]  # TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

a[int(1/1)]  # OK
```

**NB.** int conversion rounds down `int(2.5)` is `2`

Comment: So, where do I have to type cast in my original code?

Comment: Where the error showed you a was a float. It printed the exact line for you!

Comment: But I do want an output in the form of float itself